# Конвейер команд

Tags: linux, bash

Имеется некоторой текстовый файл a.txt где записаны числа - каждое на новой строке.

Требуется создать переменную-массив где каждое число - отдельный элемент. Пробовал:

```
tr "\n" " " < a.txt | read -a var1
```

Не работает (хоть и не возвращает сообщения об ошибках).

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: `$ var=($(cat a.txt)); echo ${var[@]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `mapfile`(`readarray`):

```
$ cat f
1
2
3

$ mapfile -t arr < f
$ echo ${arr[@]}
1 2 3
```

А ваш вариант можно исправить так:

```
read -a arr < <(tr "\n" " " < a.txt)
```